# AWS: Querying DynamoDB returns null

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

Newbie here. I'm trying to query a DynamoDB table from a Lambda function using partition and sort key.

My table has 5 columns, with the partition key id (string) and sort key owner (string).

Below is my lambda function. It is returning null.

```js
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.update({region: process.env.REGION});

const ddb = new AWS.DynamoDB();

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
  
  const id = event.id;
  const owner = event.owner;
  
  const params = {
    TableName: process.env.TABLE_NAME,
    KeyConditionExpression: "id = :id and owner = :owner",
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ":id": { S: id },
      ":owner": { S: owner },
    }
  };
        
  await ddb.query(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      return err;
    } else {
      return data;
    }
  });
```

My test event for the lambda function looks like:

```js
{
  "id": "someID",
  "owner": "someOwner"
}
```

I do have an item in the DDB table with the partition key id = "someID" and sort key owner = "someOwner".

Why is this function returning null?

Comment: Where in the code do you think your Lambda function handler is returning a value? Hint: it's not `return data`.

Comment: Thank you, that was part of the problem. The other part was addressed by @Conor ("owner" being a reserved DynamoDB keyword).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one immediate issue I see with the query is "owner" is a reserved DynamoDB keyword. See a list of them [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ReservedWords.html). You'll want to use the [ExpressionAttributeNames](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.ExpressionAttributeNames.html) parameter to substitute "owner" with "#owner".

I'd also suggest using the promise syntax instead of callback functions. When you return from inside `function (err, data)...`, you're actually returning from the *callback* function instead of the *lambda* function (as jarmod, hinted, beat me to it!). Here's how I'd rewrite the query:

```js
try {
  const data = await ddb.query(params).promise();
  // then, you can get the result of the query in data.Items
  console.log(data.Items);
  return data.Items;
} catch (err) {
  console.log(err);
  // return an empty array, or whatever you wish in the case of an error
  return [];
}
```

One final suggestion is to use the DynamoDB.DocumentClient instead of plain old DynamoDB. That way you don't need to specify the type of your `ExpressionAttributeValues`. So, `params` becomes:

```js
const params = {
    TableName: process.env.TABLE_NAME,
    KeyConditionExpression: "id = :id and #owner = :owner",
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ":id": id,
      ":owner": id,
    },
    ExpressionAttributeNames: {
      "#owner": "owner"
    }
  };
```

Much cleaner!

Comment: Thank you! Adding the expression attribute values, and adding a .promise() at the end of my ddb query solved the problem.